# (python and mysql) how do I manage to make the time spent between curent datetime and a certain datetime from mysql table?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

My sql table looks like this: id | name | in | out. in and out are datetimes. in is datetime from past. out is current time.
I'm not able to Select the datetime(in) from mysql table and print it. 
I tried :

```
 r=john 
 y= m.execute('SELECT in FROM table WHERE name=%s',r)
 print y
```

but not succes.

the result of print is 1

The column format is datetime. The next step after printing the date and time will be making the difference between them.

Comment: Do you mean names that end with an S ? use where name LIKE '%S'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *fetch the value from the cursor*:

```
r = john 
m.execute('SELECT in FROM table WHERE name=%s', (r, ))

date_in = m.fetchone()[0]
print(date_in)
```